# NSTextField intrinsicContentSize is always returning { NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric, 15 }, width does not resize

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

I've got a pair of editable text fields in a view using auto layout. (For completeness, these are inside an `NSTableRowView` in an editable table, but I don't think that should matter.)

[image: Editable text fields in a table row view]

I'd like the fields to resize their width based on their content, especially once they are edited.

However, `NSTextField` is not cooperating. I added some code to log the `intrinsicContentSize` whenever the edit field ends editing, and the value is *always* `{ NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric, 15 }`, meaning the field has no intrinsic width.

I've seen a lot of posts about multi-line `NSTextField` and vertical (height) resizing, wrapping, and so on, but I can't find any questions or answers that apply here. The fields are both set to "use single line", "clip", and "scroll".

I've tried sending the fields `updateConstraints` and `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` messages, but they don't seem to have any effect.

I know I can create a subclass of NSTextField and hack this, but I don't understand why this isn't working in the first place. Or maybe `NSTextField` simply doesn't have an intrinsic width, but I can't find that documented anywhere.

Note: previous answers to just set `field.editable = NO` are insufficient; these fields must be editable.

Comment: `NSTextField` doesn't have an intrinsic width if it is editable. Do you want to resize the textfield during typing or on end editing?

Comment: I guess that make sense. I'm primarily interested in resizing it to fit after editing. Ideally, I'd like the field to expand to something reasonable while being edited (I can do that with a variable width constraint), then auto-size to the content's width when not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-\[NSTextField intrinsicContentSize\] always has undefined width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809622/nstextfield-intrinsiccontentsize-always-has-undefined-width)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hack:

```
//
// Create a special text field subclass that provides an intrinsic width for its content.
// Editable NSTextFields normally do not have an intrinsic width, because I guess that would just be too weird.
// This field returns an intrinsic width when not being edited, and the width of its superview when it is.
//

@interface ResizingPatternTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation ResizingPatternTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL willEdit = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (willEdit)
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    return willEdit;
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    NSSize intrinsiceSize = super.intrinsicContentSize;
    if (self.currentEditor!=nil)
        {
        // The field is currently being edited: return the width of the superview as the intrinsic width
        // This should cause the field to expand to it's maximum width, within the constraints of the layout
        intrinsiceSize.width = self.superview.bounds.size.width;
        }
    else
        {
        // If the field isn't being edited and it's editable: calculate the width of the field ourselves
        if (self.editable)
            {
            NSDictionary* textAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName: self.font };
            NSSize textSize = [self.stringValue sizeWithAttributes:textAttrs];
            // Return an intrinsic size with a little padding, rounded up to the nearest whole integer
            intrinsiceSize.width = CGCeiling(textSize.width+7.0);
            }
        }
    return intrinsiceSize;
}
```

Notes:

- The padding value of 7.0 points is fixed (for a "small" control size) and isn't a general solution
- `CGCeiling` is just a macro for `ceil()`
- You have to make sure the hugging, compression resistance, and other layout constraints present a pleasing layout when the intrinsic width is very wide. (You should do this anyway, but here it's extra important.)