# Displaying an editable NSTextField in a NSGridView

Tags: swift, macos, nsgridview

As a fairly new Swift and MacOS developer, I typically create a prototype of a feature I want to include in my app.  Currently I'm trying to include an editable NSTextField in an NSGridView, both of which are created programmatically.  When I define the NSTextField as a label, I get expected results, as illustrated in the following:
[NSGridView with static NSTextFields][1]

However, when I change the definition of the text fields to be editable, I no longer get any visible display of the NSGridView, as illustrated here:
[NSGridView with editable NSTextFields][2]

After many hours of hunting for answers, and various trials with errors, I'm firmly convinced that I'm clueless, so any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

The code I'm working with is this, invoked from a view controller attached to the main window:

```
    override func viewDidAppear()
    {
        let t1 = NSTextField (string: "r0c0")
        let t2 = NSTextField (string: "r0c1")
        
        gridView = NSGridView (views: [
                                [t1,t2]
                            ])

        gridView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(gridView!)
        
        let winContent = view.window?.contentView!
        gridView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: winContent!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        gridView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: winContent!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

I imagine this issue is somehow related to a layout issue, but all the things I've tried have given me no results.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvYKk.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H75r9.png

Comment: Is viewDidAppear the right place to be adding constraints?

Comment: See [NSTextField intrinsicContentSize always has undefined width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809622/nstextfield-intrinsiccontentsize-always-has-undefined-width)